# Oracle DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE equivalent in PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, migration

I am trying to migrate thr Oracle function `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE` to PostgreSQL. What would be the equivalent in PostgreSQL?

```
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE(value1,value2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent in PostgreSQL.

The closest would be to set the `application_name` parameter, for example with the SQL statement `SET`.

That allows you to distinguish this database session from others on the server side.

Comment: Thank you. Please confirm if below approach is correct 
To set   :  set session.application_name to 'test'; 
To get  :  select current_setting('session.application_name')

Comment: Precisely. Additionally you can see it in `pg_stat_activity`, the list of active database sessions. That can help the DBA.